# Where is the best place to ask my question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I am a little stuck, and don't want to get shot-down by asking the wrong question on the wrong area!

I want to ask

> Is a sitara ARM9 running embedded linux is powerful enough to decode and play mpeg4 format files (using vlc or other software)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>    - **computer hardware**

[What is on-topic there](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)